# provide solution to me to combine multiple query to one which is having little difference in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, database-administration

I have below queries but I need to combine into one query, facing difficulty ,help me

### query1

```
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
  from stats_to_institution as s 
  join masterstats_innodb as m  on m.id = s.statid 
  join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
 where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' and a.streamid = 1 and a.productid >= 49  and m.access = 2  group by s.institutionid, y;
```

### query 2

```
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
  from stats_to_institution as s 
  join masterstats_innodb as m on m.id = s.statid 
  join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
 where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' and a.streamid = 5 and a.productid >= 49  and m.access = 2  group by s.institutionid, y;
```

### query 3

```
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
  from stats_to_institution as s 
  join masterstats_innodb as m on m.id = s.statid 
  join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article)
 where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' and a.streamid = 1 and a.productid >= 49 group by s.institutionid, y;
```

### query 4

```
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
  from stats_to_institution as s 
  join masterstats_innodb as m on m.id = s.statid 
  join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
 where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' and a.streamid = 5 and a.productid >= 49 group by s.institutionid, y;
```

I have created multiple queruies but want to combine into one query for the report purpose.help me

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: With emphasis on the word 'minimal', please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You shouldn't use string functions on date/time columns (i.e. use `year()` to extract the year).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select count(case when a.streamid = 1 and m.access = 2 then 1 end) as query1_count,
       count(case when a.streamid = 5 and m.access = 2  then 1 end) as query2_count,,
       count(case when a.streamid = 1 then 1 end) as query3_count,
       count(case when a.streamid = 5 then 1 end) as query4_count, 
       s.institutionid, 
       substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
  from stats_to_institution as s 
  join masterstats_innodb as m  on m.id = s.statid 
  join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
 where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) 
   and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' 
   and a.productid >= 49 and a.streamid in (1,5) 
 group by s.institutionid, y;
```

Comment: I need to combine below query with your query.Is it possible?                                                            select sum(time_on_page), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y from stats_to_institution as s join masterstats_innodb as m on m.id = s.statid where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31'  group by s.institutionid, y;

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are some better solutions but this may also help.

Here is also a link for [UNION](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all/) to choose if you want union or union all.

```
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
from stats_to_institution as s 
join masterstats_innodb as m  on m.id = s.statid 
join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) 
and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' 
and a.streamid in(1,5) 
and a.productid >= 49  
and m.access = 2  
group by s.institutionid, y
UNION 
select count(*), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y 
from stats_to_institution as s 
join masterstats_innodb as m  on m.id = s.statid 
join articles as a on a.productid = coalesce(NULLIF(video, 0), article) 
where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) 
and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31' 
and a.streamid in(1,5) 
and a.productid >= 49   
group by s.institutionid, y;
```

Comment: @AnilMoolya please let me know if that worked for you

Comment: it is working but I need to add one more query which contains sum(a) as output, query below   select sum(time_on_page), s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 4) as y from stats_to_institution as s join masterstats_innodb as m on m.id = s.statid where s.institutionid in(181, 69877 ) and m.timestamp between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31'  group by s.institutionid, y;

Comment: @AnilMoolya Add one more union at the end and place your new query. The reason I suggested you union is because as you can see there are different where conditions on each query. Please upvote and accept the answer if it is suitable for you :)